# Unable to Delete the emails using Gmail API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-cloud-console

I am trying to delete the emails from Gmail inbox using Gmail API. During this process i am getting below error.

As per the below error understand that i dont have right privileges to delete emails.

Please advise me on how to grant access in Google Cloud APP to allow Delete function.

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
> DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/188720e09bf038ef
> {
> "code" : 403,
> "details" : [ {
> "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
> "reason" : "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
> } ],
> "errors" : [ {
> "domain" : "global",
> "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
> "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
> } ],
> "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
> "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> }

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

> ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT

Means exactly that the user who has authenticated your application has not givin your application enough permissions to excuse that method.

The [messages.delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/delete) method

requires that the user have authenticated for `https://mail.google.com/` scope.  Wild guess that you have used the quickstart and have only requested read only scope.  Fix your code to request the proper scope and request authorization of the user again.